# Determining App Storage Space Requirement

Tags: ios, ipad, storage, hard-drive

I'm working on my first iPad app, and I'm using CoreData and a sqlite database for some persistent storage.  Is there a way I can tell how much hard drive space my app (and the database) is going to use once it's installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you archive your app prior to submitting it, there is a button in the Organizer that says "Estimate size". This will calculate the size of your finished app.

[image]